# Pound stopped working after fedora update

Tags: ssl, self-signed, pound

I am using Fedora 20 and recently did a yum update. Now I can't get pound to work anymore. No real errors but just refuse connection:

Following output are copy and pastes from different times but output is always same except pid and time.

```
[root@mymachine me]#  wget --no-check-certificate --debug --verbose https://localhost
Setting --verbose (verbose) to 1
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.14 on linux-gnu.

URI encoding = ‘UTF-8’
--2014-11-06 11:59:53--  https://localhost/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Caching localhost => ::1 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:443... Closed fd 3
failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:443... Closed fd 3
failed: Connection refused.
Releasing 0x0000000001f33280 (new refcount 1).
[root@mymachine me]# service pound status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  pound.service
pound.service - Pound Reverse Proxy And Load-balancer
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/pound.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2014-11-06 11:30:12 EST; 6min ago
  Process: 3019 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/pound (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 3020 (pound)
   CGroup: /system.slice/pound.service
           ├─3020 /usr/sbin/pound
           └─3021 /usr/sbin/pound

Nov 06 11:30:12 mymachine systemd[1]: Starting Pound Reverse Proxy And Load-balancer...
Nov 06 11:30:12 mymachine pound[3019]: starting...
Nov 06 11:30:12 mymachine systemd[1]: PID file /var/run/pound.pid not readable (yet?) after start.
Nov 06 11:30:12 mymachine systemd[1]: Started Pound Reverse Proxy And Load-balancer.
[root@mymachine me]# 

[root@mymachine me]# netstat -tulpn | grep pound
tcp        0      0 myip:443      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1379/pound
```

I can wget http:[stack complains about links//]localhost:80 (varnish) and wget http:[stack complains about links//]localhost:8080 (apache) I'm using a self signed pem file that can be found (no errors there), before I would have the "get me out of here" and "I know what I'm doing" from the browser but now it won't even connect with wget on localhost.

This is the /etc/pound.cfg:

```
User "pound"
Group "pound"
Control "/var/lib/pound/pound.cfg"


ListenHTTPS
    Address 128.199.217.77
    Port    443
    Cert    "/var/www/html/test.pem"
        Service
            BackEnd
                Address localhost
                Port    80
            End
        End
End
```

Answer (score 0):

It was an iptables problem. Added the rule to open port 443 with the iptables command, rules are not saved in any way when doing so. Used firewall-cmd instead:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=https
firewall-cmd --reload
firewall-cmd --list-services
```

When using wget you can't use localhost as pound isn't listening there, the command should be:

```
[root@mymachine me]#  wget --no-check-certificate --debug --verbose https://my.ip.address
```